# Cpanel Database Connection

Tags: database, laravel

I'm getting this error:

```
SQLSTATE[HY000] [1045] Access denied for user 'root122'@'localhost' (using password: YES) (SQL: select * from `basic_settings` limit 1)
```

I was able to run the database on my localhost, but getting this error when I try to run it on shared hosting.

Below is my **database.php** content:

```
'mysql' => [
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => env('DB_HOST', 'localhost'),
            'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
            'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'mitchinvest_1234'),
            'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'root122'),
            'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', '****'),
            'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
            'charset' => 'utf8mb4',
            'collation' => 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
            'strict' => true,
            'engine' => null,
        ],
```

and this is my **.env** content:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=mitchinvest_1234
DB_USERNAME=root122
DB_PASSWORD=****
```

What I have to do to run it in shared hosting?

Comment: On a side note: It is better not to publicly share credentials including database name and username. It can make hacker's life easier.

Comment: Hi @mitch, you should configure a database in your cpanel and configure it's details in the .env file. If you've already done so and still get this error, you might want to check the firewall details for the database.

Comment: It looks like the DB_username is incorrect. Since in cPanel, the DB username is always on the format cpanel-username_name. Hence, in this case the DB_USERNAME should start with *mitchinvest_*.